# UE4 Blueprint: Can I get a reference from an Actor, by the Client, if the Server spawns it?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Within the PlayerCharacterBP, I want to spawn an Actor by the Server like this:

[image: Actor spawned by Server]

And get the return value (the spawned Actor) for the client.
I was trying to do it in multiple ways, but the one that would make any kind of sense in my head would have been this:

[image: Actor spawned by Server and get reference through "Run on owning client" Event]

However, the variable "SpawnedAbility" always returns NULL.

Am I doing something fatally wrong here or is it actually possible to spawn an Actor by the Server and get its reference for the owning client?

UE 4.22.3 | Listen Server

Comment: After trying out many things and informing myself as much as I could, I am almost certain, there is no way to do it as simple, as I did in this example.

It makes sense, that it would not be possible, because the server spawns and replicates the object and has authority over it. I guess I made a "beginners mistake" here, thinking this easy way might be possible, which also leads me to a different code design.

I did not answer on this post, as I am by no means super experienced or educated in this and cannot say for certainty that what I am saying is legit, I just wanted others to know.

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, there seems to be a [post](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/29674/view.html) that claims this is possible, but apparently only in a workaround kind of way.
That is why I said "I am almost certain, there is no way to do it as simple, as I did in this example".